# Convenient way to replace findviewbyid by butterknife annotation in whole project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way that I can replace all findviewbyid formulas by Butterknife @Inject(id) annotation automatically or I have to do it manually? I use Android Studio IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written some regular expressions to handle the search and replace task. It may not be worth it for you though, depending on how many statements you have.

I used SublimeText to run the queries, it supports newline which I need. IntelliJ didn't match newlines in the query I tried. I think sed could also be used (check sed manual for 'advanced' switch or something).

**Search Pattern for Strings:**

```
private (String) (\w+);((?:.|\n)*)\1 = \w*.getString\(R.string.(\w*)\);
```

**Replace Pattern for Strings:**

```
@BindString(R.string.$4)\n    $1 $2;$3
```

**Search Pattern for View ids**

```
(?:private |public |protected |)(\w*) (\w+)(?:\s*=\s*null|);((?:.|\n)*)\s\2 = .*findViewById\(R.id.(\w*)\);
```

In the above I added the search for fields declared with other modifiers.

**Replace Pattern for View ids**

```
@Bind(R.id.$4)\n    $1 $2;$3
```

You may wish to replace spaces with \s*, but it makes expressions more difficult to read, so I didn't do it in every location.

**Example of what it does**

```
private View map_center;
someMethod() {
    ...
    map_center = activityOrView.findViewById(R.id.centerview);
    ...
}
```

becomes

```
@Bind(R.id.centerview)
View map_center;
someMethod() {
    ...
    ...
}
```

The regular expression uses the back reference `\1` to locate the assignment of the field. If the field is not there but is a local variable, it'll wrap the local variable with @Bind and you'll manually have to make it a field. It won't match local variables with declaration in same line as assignment.

Comment: @arberg what about multiple declarations in a single line, any idea how to handle that with a regex ?

Comment: It is possible the regexp can be changed to support your case. I can recommend online tools to build and test the regexp at the same time: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-using-butter-knife-to-inject-views-on-android--cms-23542) I should say yes!:

> The Butter Knife library, developer and maintained by Jake Wharton
>   (Square Inc.), has annotations that help developers to instantiate the
>   views from our activity or fragment. It also has annotations to handle
>   events like `onClick()`, `onLongClick()`, etc.
>
> In every activity or fragment, you have to remove, or comment out,
>   every call of the `findViewById()` method and add the `@InjectView`
>   annotation before the declaration of the variable, indicating the
>   identifier of the view.

```
@InjectView(R.id.sample_textview)
TextView sample_textview;
```

Comment: Hi, I clarified my question. I just want to do it automatically via some kind of tool or script